# Angular 8 ngStyle sometimes does not work inside a loop

Tags: angular, firebase, angular8, ng-style

I have the following code in Angular 8.

```
<mat-grid-list cols="5" rowHeight="16:9" gutterSize="1%">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let m of media; index as i">
        <div class="media-cards" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + m.thumbnail + ')'}"></div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

For some strange and unknown reason, it does not add `background-image` style in some of the elements generated in the loop. `m.thumbnail` is a valid URL and available for each element of the `media` object.

This is how it looks (background image missing):
[image: Out put]

This is how the generated code looks like:
[image: Geneated code]

You can see in the image above that `background-image` style is missing for the second element.

Why is it happening like this? Where is the problem?

Comment: Does adding a semicolon to the end of your background style affect anything? 'url(' + m.thumbnail + ');'

Comment: @Mickers I was expecting that adding the semicolon would not make any difference. But to my surprise, after adding the semicolon I notice that the style is not added to any of the 4 elements while without it the style is added to 2 elements and not added to 2 elements.

Comment: I have added another style to the ngStyle object. `{'background-image': 'url(' + m.thumbnail + ')', 'background-color': 'pink'}`. `'background-color': 'pink'` is added to all four elements, while `background-image` is missing on two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out some of the URLs have parentheses (... Fitness%20(10).JPG ...). So, when when I use the style `'background-image': 'url(__the_url__)'`, it breaks because of the parentheses. It looks like Angular might be validating the styles before it adds to the element. As these rules don't validate due to the parentheses, those are not added to the elements.

So, I wrapped the URLs in single quotes to make it a string literal so that the parentheses won't create an issue and it will work properly. And it worked.

`{'background-image': 'url(\'' + m.thumbnail + '\')'}`